# Add Open Sans font to Outlook HTML Email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I've been trying to add the Open Sans font to a HTML email which will work in Outlook 2013.

I've tried using the CSS @Import and Google Fonts with no luck.

Does anyone know how?

Of the 2 processes mentioned above, they do work in other email clients such as Gmail, which is no surprise but my company and our clients primarily use Outlook so i'm trying my hardest to get Open Sans working.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No such luck with Outlook custom fonts:
http://www.emaildesignreview.com/html-email-coding/web-fonts-in-email-1482/

Also because you're trying to add a custom font, the fall backs don't render in Outlook so it renders the text in Times New Roman.
You can read this article/thread for a way to stop Outlook from doing that:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7931/google-web-fonts-fallback-issues/

Please up vote if this was helpful :)